# Do any teaching methods explicitly rely on the role of the subconscious in language acquisition?

Tags: teaching-methods, learning-psychology

It seems like language functions best when it is subconscious, like how people use their native languages. Are there any teaching methods that address this?

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. As it currently stands, your question is too broad. It appears to ask about the role of the subconscious in language learning in general, while the tag you added refers to `teaching-methods` only. Could you please make your question more specific.

Comment: You could look into the _Natural Approach_, a very influential second language teaching methodology developed by Krashen and Terrell: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_approach